# groupby with summarise in R on a column of class character

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe with columns A and B where B is a character string I want to groupby column A and the combine the elements of B into a string where I can then get the unique elements of that grouped characters (using R 4.0.5 and `dplyr`).

Example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), c = c("d","d","d","d","e","e"))

df.new <- df %>%
             group_by(a) %>%
             summarise(new_strs = c(c))
```

which outputs this `data.frame`:

```
1 a     d       
2 a     d       
3 a     d       
4 b     d       
5 b     e       
6 b     e
```

Desired DF output:

```r
1 a     c("d","d","d")             
6 b     c("d","e","e")
```

How can I change the code to get the result. I also tried `paste(x, collapse = ",")` but it gives a single string rather then a group of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `aggregate` from `base R`

```
aggregate(c ~ a, df, list)
  a       c
1 a d, d, d
2 b d, e, e
```

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is to use `list` rather than `c`

```
exampledf <- data.frame(a = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), c = c("d","d","d","d","e","e"))

exampledf %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise(new_strs = list(c))
```

Comment: Yeah the answer is this, but the desired output is not correct..
```r
example_df %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  summarise(c = list(unique(c))) %>%
  identity()
```